# How can I get cache_nodes address from ElastiCache in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache

In Terraform, I am creating a single ElastiCache cluster:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "api" {
  cluster_id           = var.cluster_id
  engine               = var.engine
  node_type            = var.node_type
  num_cache_nodes      = 1
  parameter_group_name = "default.redis3.2"
  engine_version       = "3.2.4"
  port                 = 6379
  subnet_group_name    = var.subnet_group_name
}
```

I am wondering how I can access the `address` attribute exported by `cache_nodes`

Is either of the following sufficient?

```
output "redis_host1" {
  value = aws_elasticache_cluster.api.cache_nodes["address"]
}

output "redis_host2" {
  value = aws_elasticache_cluster.api.cache_nodes.address
}
```

Just looking for some clarification, please.

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempt? Any errors?

Comment: │ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on ../../../Providers/AWS/aws_elasticache_cluster/outputs.tf line 2, in output "redis_host":
│    2:   value = aws_elasticache_cluster.api.cache_nodes["address"]
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required.

Comment: output "redis_host" {
  value = aws_elasticache_cluster.api.cache_nodes[0].address
} -- this appears to be valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cache_nodes](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_cluster#cache_nodes) is a **list**. So you have to specify index of the node first, e.g.:

```
output "redis_host1" {
  value = aws_elasticache_cluster.api.cache_nodes[0].address
}

output "redis_host2" {
  value = aws_elasticache_cluster.api.cache_nodes[1].address
}
```

or just return addresses as list:

```
output "redis_hosts" {
  value = aws_elasticache_cluster.api.cache_nodes[*].address
}
```